# unit test for a method using generics

Tags: java, generics, junit, hamcrest

I took from this forum a following method and I cannot get my head around how to write a junit test. I looked in the forum for answers but have not found anything concrete. Hopefully someone knows?

This is my method:

```
public String replaceName( Class<? extends Command> cmd) {
 String str = cmd.getSimpleName().replaceAll("Command$", "");
}
```

With hamcrest I am trying something like:

```
@Test
public void testIfBackupCommandIsChildOfCommand() {
  Class<? extends Command> cmd ;

   assertThat( expected, (Matcher) org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf(cmd));
}
```

I have to initialize the cmd in order for this to work. I am not sure how to do that. If I initialize to null I get a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

This generic means that you are passing as a parameter any class that extends the Command class. You will have to either create a class that extends the Command class or use an existing implementation. I'm not sure what the Command class is in your case, whether it's a concrete or abstract class, or if there are existing implementations, so I can't make any suggestions without more information.

As I mentioned, you may be able to just create your own class and use it though:

```
class MyClass extends Command {
   public MyClass() {}

   public void implementedMethod() {}
}
```